How do I switch from LLVM to MSVC with Visual Studio?
I'm using a dependency that requires MSVC to work (I'm not sure why; that's just what the docs said), and I'd like to switch from Clang/LLVM to Visual C++ (MSVC) to make it work. How do I do this without deleting LLVM?
I've tried all sorts of web pages and whatnot, but I unfortunately couldn't find anything about Clang to Visual C++, only the other way around.
Here's the specific code I need to compile (just in case there's an X/Y problem happening here, though I highly doubt that).
// I know it's old-fashioned, but it's all I need
#include <curses.h>

int main(void)
{
  // TEST
  addstr("Hello World!");
}

I get this error.
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol addstr referenced in function main
LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I'm using the NuGet PDCurses package (not the Win32 specific one, the other one).
Thank you for any help!

The pdcurses tag is added.   Are you compiling a project that uses pdcurses? Please provide specific error information and minimal reproducible examples.

@MinxinYu-MSFT Thank you! I added an example, the error, and information about the library I was including.

I downloaded  pdcurses from nuget.
Then find the folder:
<your solution folder>\packages\PDCurses34.3.4.0.1\build\native\lib\x64\v141\dynamic\Debug


Add the folder path. Right click your project -> properties -> Linker ->  General -> Additional library  Directories.

Add lib In Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies :   pdcurses.lib

Find the redist folder, copy the dll to the same folder as output exe.


<your solution folder>\packages\PDCurses34.redist.3.4.0.1\build\native\bin\x64\v141\dynamic\Debug

